# How can I emulate an HTTPS request under WebTest?

Tags: python, https, pyramid, webtest

I have a Pyramid app that locks down certain functionality to HTTPS connections.

The server is fronted by nginx (usually) and I use PasteDeploy to detect the HTTPS connection. From my environment.ini:

```
[filter:proxy-prefix]
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix
```

If the connection is HTTPS, paste deploy sets the `request.scheme` variable to `'https'`.

I'm trying to write some integrated tests right now, and I can't seem to figure out how to get the `TestApp`, as provided by webtest, to process a request as if it were HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are loading your full WSGI pipeline which includes your filters. If you are not, then the headers won't be translated by the middleware. Generally this means calling `get_app` on "main" instead of "myapp". Also I'd suggest trying WebTest's `extra_environ` option which may work, since ultimately the middleware is just setting `environ['wsgi.url_scheme']`.

```
testapp.get('/foo', extra_environ={'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https'})
```

Comment: could you describe this a little more:

     Generally this means calling get_app on "main" instead of "myapp". 

Based on other's test suites, I have essentially this:

    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.app = main({}, **settings)


    def setUp(self):
        self.app = TestApp(self.app)
        self.config = testing.setUp()

    def test__something(self):
        self.app.get()

I tried passing in the wsgi.url_scheme to the extra_environ -- no luck.

i might have to refactor my apps code to look for environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] instead of request.scheme

Comment: "`cls.app = main({}, **settings)`" does **not** load the INI file, thus the prefix middleware is not included. This means that you have to do the work of the middleware yourself and set the `wsgi.url_scheme` environ parameter yourself. If you want middleware, you can add it manually `app = paste.deploy.config.PrefixMiddleware(app)`, or you can load a test ini file `app = pyramid.paster.get_app('testing.ini#main')` which will load the full wsgi stack defined by the "main" section of the INI.

Comment: settings was previously set as:

settings = appconfig('config:' + os.path.join(here, '../../', 'development.ini'))

i understand the get_app functionality now.  going to try it.  thanks a ton.

Comment: based on your description, it seems to be more like this command:

self.app = TestApp(pyramid.paster.get_app('development.ini#main'))

i've run into a few issues with webtest. it looks like i'll need to patch it to set 'scheme' if the wsgi.url_scheme is set ( it's currently doing the opposite ). it also seems to ignore specified headers after the first call to get() is made, i haven't figured out how/why yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried combing through the docs a third time, and figured out a workaround based on PasteDeploy ( perhaps the right solution )...

PasteDeploy looks for 2 headers to set the https connection.  I added them to the headers dict I use to manage the cookie session, and it seemed to work fine at first.

```
{
   "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEME" : 'https',
   "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" : 'https',
}
```

PasteDeploy has an if/else chain, so only one is needed... but submitting both works.

the PasteDeploy doesn't seem to get called though - i see these headers/environment items in the app, but the https isn't set.